# Solution Explorer for Visual Studio C# 2013 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm running VS 2013 Express targetting 4.5. I have a Windows Forms test app called ConfigMgrTest2. Two questions as I move around the Solution Explorer:

(1) Using the Settings Designer tool, I created an Application setting called 'applicationSetting1'. To access this setting, I need this syntax:

```
var r = ConfigMgrTest2.Properties.Settings.Default.applicationSetting1;
```

I don't understand why I need to call this through the Default property. Both Default and 'applicationSetting' are members of the Settings class. And 'Default' pertains to the 'defaultInstance' Why not call my 'applicationSetting' directly like this:

```
var r = ConfigMgrTest2.Properties.Settings.applicationSetting1;
```

(2) The Settings class is created in two parts. In the Settings.Designer.cs file, the Default property is created. In Settings.cs, the Settings event handlers are created. In one of my projects, I can see the Settings.cs file in Solution Explorer but in another, I seem to be missing this node.

Comment: I was wondering the same about the Default property but I never asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your setting (`applicationSetting1` in this case) is an instance member of the `Settings` class. The `Default` property represents an instance of that class via a Singleton pattern. In order to do what you want to do in your second example you would constantly need to be creating an instance of `Settings` in your code, for example:

```
var settings = new ConfigMgrTest2.Properties.Settings();
var r = settings.applicationSetting1;
```

This would be a pain for the develop and also potentially leave you with several instances of the class hanging around.

I just took a look in my copy of Visual Studio 2013 (Professional). I see the Settings.settings file, which is an XML file, and the Settings.Designer.cs file, which is the C# code that actually generates the `Settings` class code.

Comment: I see how this line, var r = ConfigMgrTest2.Properties.Settings.Default.applicationSetting1;,

Comment: This replaces the edit above: Thanks for your note. I see how the Singleton syntax is shorter. I'm still not clear, however, how 'applicationSetting1', which is a property, is accessed through another property, Default.

Comment: Also have a look at this answer to a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24624453/1662314

Comment: Default is a property that returns an instance of an object (i.e. the Settings object). If a property returns an instance of an object then properties of that object can be accessed.